# Polymer, adding new item in nested Array in not getting rendered by dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x, dom-repeat

I have a nested array and I need to add new subject for multiple persons, but for keeping it simple I will add new subject to Jon only.

```
[
      {
        gender: "male",
        persons: [
          {
            name: "Jon",
            subjects: [
              { subName: "maths", marks: "45" },
              { subName: "phy", marks: "47" },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        gender: "female",
        persons: [
          {
            name: "Amily",
            subjects: [{ subName: "bio", marks: "43" }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

I will add subject on button click.

```
addSubject() {
    /* This doesn't work */
    let newData = [...this.data];
    newData[0].persons[0].subjects.push({ subName: "chem", marks: "50" });
    this.data = newData;
}
```

It works if I use `this.push("data.0.persons.0.subjects", { subName: "chem", marks: "50" });` but if I need to add subjects to multiple persons,this method will update property every time. Above could accumulate all changes in temporary array only update once.

Render

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
  <div>Gender: [[item.gender]]</div>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.persons]]">
    <div>Name: [[item.name]]</div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.subjects]]">
        <div>Subject: [[item.subName]], [[item.marks]]</div>
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

If I try rendering simpler data, then its working fine

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[simpleData]]">
   <div>Subject: [[item.subName]], [[item.marks]]</div>
</template>

static get properties() {
  return {
     simpleData: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true,
        value: () => [
          { subName: "math", marks: "11" },
          { subName: "phy", marks: "22" },
        ],
     },
}
addSubjectInSimple() {
    let newData = [...this.simpleData];
    newData.push({ subName: "chem", marks: "50" });
    this.simpleData = newData;
}
```

Comment: Try updating data directly - not via a copy - `this.data[0].persons[0].subjects.push({ subName: "chem", marks: "50" }); this.data = [...this.data];`.

Comment: FYI, Polymer was declared death years ago. https://lit.dev its successor

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Maintaining old project 

Comment: That means you are learning old technology, not new technology. I would switch jobs. Polymer will never reach Cobol status (developers now make 120K+)

Comment: @G.Tranter This is not updating the dom

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [`mutable-data`](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-repeat#DomRepeat-property-mutableData) attribute on your dom-repeat. This tells polymer to look out for deep changes any time the object changes. (You still need to call `this.set` or `this.notifyPath`to trigger the dom update.)

Polymer tries very hard (sometimes too hard) to *not* update the dom when it doesn't *think* it needs to, which is why it does [dirty checking](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/mixins/mutable-data) on `dom-repeat`s. You are using a more modern approach when you create your `newData` object and change it, which modern browsers can usually handle, but Polymer needs "permission" to use that approach.

**Note:** Object spread `...` is doing a shallow copy of your object, *not* a deep clone. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61422332/16625307) for more on that.)

Comment: Do I need to add ```mutable-data``` to both the ```dom-repeat``` or which one? Also if top ```dom-repeat``` is in Parent component and inner one is in child component, do I need to extend both parent and child classes with ```Polymer.MutableData``` mixin

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I would try it both ways to see, but I think you will at least need it on the top-level `dom-repeat`. That's the one that should be directly observing the object you are re-setting. Sorry I cannot be more exact, even internally we usually have to do a lot of fiddling to get it to work just right.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following for the line `this.data = newData;`:
`this.set("data", newData);`.

It could still fail to update based on Tanner Stern's response that you are working on a shallow copy as it is technically still the same object and Polymer may see it as not being updated. You can quickly clone the array with: `let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));`

This should force Polymer to set the entire array to the new values as well as notify the dom that it has been changed. Usually (in my personal experience in the past 5 years), Polymer doesn't like to acknowledge notifications on anything further in than one child access, eg. obj.obj but not obj.obj.obj or further down, so I've found that the best is to set the entire array/object with the Polymer `set` function.