# React State modification despite the fact I used spread operator to avoid direct modification of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deep-copy, spread-syntax

I tried to use spread operator to avoid modifications of my state without the use the set State. But despite that, my state is still modified.

I can eventually make a deepCopy of my state but I don't really understand why it is needed here.

Thanks in advance for your help !

```
const resultTypeIdsNeedsCheckAll = [2,3]
  const selectResultType = (resultType) => {
    setResultType(resultType);
    const selectedStatParamsCopy = {...selectedStatParams}
    // Check if resultType.id is in the array resultTypeIdsNeedsCheckAll
    if (resultTypeIdsNeedsCheckAll.includes(resultType.id)) {

        selectedStatParamsCopy.parentSuggestions.slice(0, selectedStatParamsCopy.parentSuggestions.length - 1).map(parentSugg => {
          parentSugg.childSuggestions.map(childSugg => childSugg.isActiveCheckBox = 1)
          parentSugg.isAbsenceOfPatientInfoChecked = 1
        })

      }
    }
```

Comment: The spread operator doesn't perform a deep copy, it just puts the same object references into a new array.  If you're mutating those same object references then you are modifying the objects directly.  Note also that you're somewhat mis-using `.map()` here, these should be `.forEach()` operations instead since you're not doing anything with the result of `.map()`.  You *could* use `.map()` to make copies of array properties in state, but it's not clear what the intent of this functionality is in the first place since nothing uses the modified data afterward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object copy using spread syntax actually shallow or deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421873/object-copy-using-spread-syntax-actually-shallow-or-deep)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

the map is not necessary it's a mistake thank you. 

So is there any way despite deepCopy to perform what I want ?

Otherwise Is it problematic to directly modify the state without performing a set State ?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do and why.  Currently the code shown mutates state and does nothing else.  Do you want to update state instead?  Do you want to make a copy of state to use somewhere else?  For what purpose?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions I understand better the differences between shallow and deepCopy !

I think the best practice is to copy the state and update It with a set state of the copy, am I wrong ?

Otherwise mutating the state without making a deep copy of it could be ok for me, but I don't think it is a good practice in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal here is to update state with a new copy of state, or if your goal is to create some copy of state for some other purpose, in either case what you *shouldn't* do is directly mutate state.  Which is exactly what these operations do:

```
childSugg.isActiveCheckBox = 1
```

and:

```
parentSugg.isAbsenceOfPatientInfoChecked = 1
```

With the caveat that I don't know your data model or what operation you're trying to perform, but it's not clear what that `.slice()` operation is even trying to do.  What *is* clear however is that you want to make deeper and deeper copies of any object you want to modify.

A common pattern to do that is nested spread operators and `.map()` operations, at each level where a copy is needed.  For example, consider this:

```
const newStateValue = {
  ...selectedStatParams,
  parentSuggestions: selectedStatParams.parentSuggestions.map(parentSugg => {
    return {
      ...parentSugg,
      isAbsenceOfPatientInfoChecked: 1,
      childSuggestions: parentSugg.childSuggestions.map(childSugg => {
        return {
          ...childSugg,
          isActiveCheckBox: 1
        };
      })
    };
  })
}
```

So, starting at the top level of the `selectedStatParams` object (which I'm assuming is an object stored in state that you want to update):

- Use the spread operator to make a copy of that object's properties into a new object reference,
- Set the `parentSuggestions` property to the result of a `.map()` operation over that same property, in which we:

  - Use the spread operator to make a copy of each object's properties into a new object reference,
  - Set the `isAbsenceOfPatientInfoChecked` property to `1`,
  - Set the `childSuggestions` property to the result of a `.map()` operation over that same property, in which we:

    - Use the spread operator to make a copy of each object's properties into a new object reference,
    - Set the `isActiveCheckBox` property to `1`

As you can see, it's just the same simple pattern repeated at each level of nesting.  The spread operator is used to simply say "copy the rest of the properties that this operation doesn't need to modify".  And `.map()` is used to project any array into a new array in which that pattern is repeated.

So at no point are you *assigning* a value to an *existing* property, but instead always creating *new* objects in which you can set those property values to whatever you need.